# Making a 5x5 Board using a grid in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im making one of my first programs, using python, tkinter and pillow.

This program is supposed to randomly select one of four tile images, create an image and repeat 25 times
Making a 5x5 Board using a grid to position the images in a square.

*This is not what happened when i ran my code though*

One or two columns and 4 rows are usually generated and not every coordinate is filled with an image.
And only the corner of the images are visible for some reason?
The images center seems to be placed in the top left corner of their grid.

A output might look something like this

X = coordinate filled with an image

O = coordinate filled with bg colour

---

X X

O X

O X

---

When i want it to look like this

---

X  X  X  X  X

X  X  X  X  X

X  X  X  X  X

X  X  X  X  X

X  X  X  X  X

---

The code thats supposed to place the images looks like this

```
while n < 25:
n = n + 1
number = random.randint(1,4)

if number == 1:

    TILE_FLOWER.grid(row = x, column = y)
    TILE_FLOWER.create_image(16,16, image = TILE_FLOWER_IMG)

elif number == 2:
    TILE_GRASS.grid(row = x, column = y)
    TILE_GRASS.create_image(16,16, image = TILE_GRASS_IMG)

elif number == 3:
    TILE_STONE.grid(row = x, column = y)
    TILE_STONE.create_image(16,16, image = TILE_STONE_IMG)

elif number == 4:
    TILE_WATER.grid(row = x, column = y,)
    TILE_WATER.create_image(16,16, image = TILE_WATER_IMG)

if x == 5:
    x = 0
    y = y + 1

else:
    x = x + 1


win.mainloop()
```

---

The code defining my canvases looks like this
   They're the same size as the images i want to draw on them.

---

```
TILE_FLOWER = Canvas(win, height = 80, width = 80)
TILE_GRASS = Canvas(win, height = 80, width = 80)
TILE_STONE = Canvas(win, height = 80, width = 80)
TILE_WATER = Canvas(win, height = 80, width = 80)
```

---

And lastly the code defining the images looks like this

---

```
TILE_FLOWER_IMG = PhotoImage(file = 'Path1.png')
TILE_GRASS_IMG = PhotoImage(file = 'Path2.png')
TILE_STONE_IMG = PhotoImage(file = 'Path3.png')
TILE_WATER_IMG = PhotoImage(file = 'Path4.png')
```

---

Hope what i've written makes sense!
    And i would be super thankful if someone could help me fix this mess :)

Comment: You aren't creating a new Canvas for each cell of your grid; you have exactly four of them, and are simply moving them to a new location each time they are randomly chosen again.

Comment: Is it a must to use `Canvas` to display the image? If not, better use `Label`.  Also since your code does not specify `anchor` option in `create_image(...)`, it is default to `center`.  That means the given (x, y) in the `create_image()` is the center of the image.  Either set `anchor='nw'` or set (x, y) to (40, 40).

Comment: @acw1668 

Thanks for the tip! 
Label worked a bit easier than using canvas haha and the images are now centered!

Comment: @jasonharper

That makes sense thank you! 
Do you have any idea where i should look if i want to learn how to make new Canvases (or labels) with each iteration of the loop? I've been looking for a while and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new `Label` or `Canvas` in each cell of the 5x5 grid:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

imagelist = [
    tk.PhotoImage(file='Path1.png'),
    tk.PhotoImage(file='Path2.png'),
    tk.PhotoImage(file='Path3.png'),
    tk.PhotoImage(file='Path4.png'),
]

for i in range(25):
    image = random.choice(imagelist)
    tk.Label(root, image=image, width=80, height=80, bg='white').grid(row=i//5, column=i%5)
    '''
    # or using Canvas
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
    canvas.create_image(40, 40, image=image)
    canvas.grid(row=i//5, column=i%5)
    '''

root.mainloop()
```

Or using single `Canvas`:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg='white')
canvas.pack()

for i in range(25):
    image = random.choice(imagelist)
    row = i // 5
    col = i % 5
    canvas.create_image(40+col*80, 40+row*80, image=image)
```